# Poission/Normal and Beta distribution in Python - Help understanding the statistics

Tags: python, numpy, math, statistics

I have some question about this python code. I need help to understand the output answers. I have a simple great code in python for generating poission, normal and beta distribution, I want help to understand the figures that come out.

Before posting my code, lets think of a simple scenario: Each minute a certain amount of car is coming in to the city, the mean arrival is 63 and sigma is 25,

ok so here is my code:

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu, sigma = 64, 24


#normal distribution
s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)

count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, 30, normed=True)

plt.plot(bins, 1/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) *
         np.exp( - (bins -mu )**2 / (2 * sigma**2)),
    linewidth=2, color='r')
plt.show()



#Poisson distribution

s = np.random.poisson(5, 10000)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, 14, normed=True)
plt.show()


#Beta distribution

s = np.random.beta(mu, sigma, 1000)


count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, 30, normed=True)
plt.show()
```

Here is result of the code:

[Poisson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVcje.png)

[Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4oFP.png)

[Beta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT9vR.png)

Question 1: What do these numbers tell based on the scenario?

Question 2: Is it possible to change the X lines (-0,15 to 175 on poisson), (-3 to 4 on normal) and (0.55 to 0.85 on beta)?

Questions 3 and 4: I have asked inside the code.

Thank you

Comment: This would be better suited for the [Statistics SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). While people here most likely also have some knowledge of statistics, undoubtedly you could get more information there, as this site mainly handles programming issues such as code not working as expected / at all.

Comment: I hope this isn't some homework assignment you're asking us to do for you. With regards to the questions in your code, you can easily figure out what the numbers mean by doing a Google search on those numpy methods. Also, you have labeled the first distribution as Poisson, but you're using a normal distribution to randomly draw out numbers. Same thing with the normal label, where you're using a t distribution instead.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr sorry i posted a wrong one, here is my real code ;)

But to a programming specific question then: how can i change the lines underneath the diagram?

Comment: @Giroud2 You want to plot the pdf of the distributions, just like how you plotted it in your normal distribution plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a general comment, you don't seem to have "done your homework" before asking questions. Most people recommend a bit of study and familiarity with the subject matter **before** asking questions, and feel that's better for you, and for those who puzzle over your questions. That said, let's have a go at your questions, and then, please pick up an introductory book on probability and statistics - or just Google it, and start reading.

```
"Question 1: What does these numbers tell based on the scenario?"
```

A1: This question is so unclear that it cannot possibly be answered, except to say "Yes".

```
"Question 2: Is it possible to change the X lines(-0,15 to 175 on poission), 
(-3 to 4 on normal) and 
(0.55 to 0.85 on beta)?"
```

A2: Of course... you can change these values to anything you like, but how does that advance your efforts here? In other words, what is it you are trying to do?

```
QUESTION 3: WHAT IS THIS NUMBER 3830?
```

A3: Mmmm... you've really given yourself away here as you've shown that you've not RTFM. `numpy` has lots of documentation available, and in fact [here's a reference that answers your Q3](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html): `3830` is the number of samples to draw from the distribution with the mean and variance you've specified.

```
QUESTION 4: AND WHAT ARE THESE NUMBERS?
```

A4: Same answer as #3 really, only in this case, the distribution is called ["Student's t"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution), and the [numpy reference provides the answer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.standard_t.html): The numbers are the `degrees of freedom` of the distribution, and the number of samples to be drawn from that distribution.

Comment: Thanks boss. I will take notes on this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot the pdf (Poisson will be pmf since it is a discrete distribution), then I would suggest using `scipy` which you are already using.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm, poisson, beta

mu, sigma = 64, 24

# normal
s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)
x = np.linspace(norm.ppf(0.001, mu, sigma), norm.ppf(0.999, mu, sigma), 300)
plt.hist(s, 30, normed=True)
plt.plot(x, norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma), 'r', lw=2)
plt.title("Normal with mu=64, sigma=24")
plt.show()

# poisson
s = np.random.poisson(5, 10000)
x = np.arange(poisson.ppf(0.001, 5), poisson.ppf(0.999, 5))
plt.hist(s, 14, normed=True)
plt.plot(x, poisson.pmf(x, 5), 'r')
plt.title("Poisson with mu=5")
plt.show()

# beta
s = np.random.beta(mu, sigma, 1000)
x = np.linspace(beta.ppf(0.001, mu, sigma), beta.ppf(0.999, mu, sigma), 300)
plt.hist(s, 30, normed=True)
plt.plot(x, beta.pdf(x, mu, sigma), 'r')
plt.title("Beta with mu=64, sigma=24")
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate! Really appreciate.